# PHP Convert in date and update a database (PhpMyAdmin) with a date (like 22:43:50)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i don't understand why i can't update my DataBase with times like "21:20:46".

```
$tempsPassage = date(' H:i:s', 1647724846); //timestamp to date
echo $tempsPassage; // it shows corretly the time i want like "21:20:46".
   $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE chrono SET time = $tempsPassage WHERE  ......");
  $stmt->execute();
```

My table in PhpMyAdmin is in time unit. i already tried to update time differently like `SET time = 212046` and it updated my table to `21:20:46`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FROM_UNIXTIME is amysql function that will work just fine

> ```
> SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1647724846, '%h:%i:%s');
> ```
>
> ```
> | FROM_UNIXTIME(1647724846, '%h:%i:%s') |
> | :------------------------------------ |
> | 09:20:46                              |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fb7e29fe98ac4d9b8e0914e5151942f5)*

But your code is vulnerable to sql injection, use always place holders and parameters.

```
$tempsPassage = 1647724846; //timestamp to date
echo $tempsPassage; // it shows corretly the time i want like "21:20:46".
   $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE chrono SET time = FROM_UNIXTIME(?, '%h:%i:%s') WHERE  ......");
   $stmt->bind_param("s", tempsPassage );
  $stmt->execute();
```

And for your information phpmyadnun is a gui written in php to manage mysql databases